# Ignore count with zero values not working with sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query

```
select id , ( select count(*) .... ) as c
     from Foo
        where c > 0
        order by c desc
```

I got `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'c' in 'where clause'`

So how can I ignore count with zero values with a sub query ?

Comment: *It is not allowable to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause, because the column value might not yet be determined when the WHERE clause is executed.*

Comment: thanks @juergend but how can i ignore count with zero values ?

Comment: hThe way you are querying it count will always be one. Please post your table structure and explain what you want to get a count of

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from (
  select id, (select count(*)... ) as c from Foo
) x 
where c > 0
order by c desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
As from MySQL site:
```

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

Refer to [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Any way:

> You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column.